# How do I configure Event Processors in Axon with Spring?

Tags: event-handling, axon

Apparently Axon uses `TrackingEventProcessors` by default. I would like to use `SubscribingEventProcessors` instead. The [docs](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/spring-boot-autoconfiguration#event-handling-configuration) say that [the latter is already the default](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/1.3-infrastructure-components/event-processing#event-handlers), but they seem to be outdated.

> By default, Axon will use Subscribing Event Processors. It is possible
>   to change how Handlers are assigned and how processors are configured
>   using the EventHandlingConfiguration class of the Configuration API.

For instance, it is suggested to perform configurations like so:

```
@Autowired
public void configure(EventHandlingConfiguration config) {
    config.usingTrackingProcessors(); // default all processors to tracking mode.
}
```

However, there is no `EventHandlingConfiguration` in v4 (there was in v3).

I need to use the `SubscribingEventProcessors` to perform read-model updates in the same transaction as command handling. How can this be configured in 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This aspect of event processors can be configured in `application.yml/application.properties`

```
axon:
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      NAME_OF_THE_PROCESSOR:
        mode: subscribing
```

I think you are right. Documentation is referencing old API.

You can configure all event processors builders to use SubscribingEventProcessor

```
 @Autowired
 public void configure(EventProcessingConfigurer configurer) {
      configurer.usingSubscribingEventProcessors(); 
 }
```

https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/blob/axon-4.0/config/src/main/java/org/axonframework/config/EventProcessingConfigurer.java#L216

Best,
Ivan

Comment: Thanks! Did you find a `EventProcessingConfigurer` in v4, though? That's what I initially tried and could only find such class in v3. I would like to configure **all** processors at once.

Comment: `EventProcessingConfigurer` is new API - v4

Comment: `EventHandlingConfiguration` is old API - v3. It is not available in v4

Comment: Documentation will be updated. There is an open pull request on the 'guide' repo: https://github.com/AxonIQ/reference-guide/pull/25